# Use UL and LI as select or option box using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<ul class="stateid">

<li value="7" >pa</li>
<li value="8" >ap</li>
<li value="9" >pat</li>
<li value="19" >part</li>
</ul>
```

Wat I have tried so far is

```
$".stateid li").click(function(){

alert($(this).val());
});
```

Should only display the clicked li rest should be hidden

I can fetch the value but not able to display just the selected state using jquery

Comment: It's up to you to create the selected state.

Comment: Just need to display the clicked state

Comment: value attr of li tag is deprecated... any why not just the drop down..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you simply want to hide all other li after cicking on one li.. If so, then below would do the trick,

```
var $lis = $(".stateid li");
$lis.click(function() {
  $lis.not($(this)).hide();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/Gm8N9/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Ar first you must write your selector inside parentheses like this

```
$(".stateid li").click(function(){

alert($(this).val());
});​
```

If you want to alert `pa` and `ap` instead of `7` and `8`, use text function instead of `val`.

```
$(".stateid li").click(function(){
alert($(this).text());
});​
```

See working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Gm8N9/

**EDIT:**

To show only clicked li use this

```
$(".stateid li").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings().hide();
    });​
```

And jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Gm8N9/2/

Comment: Just need to display the selected li

Comment: What you mean under "display selected li"? All li's are displayed by default.

Comment: Yup by clicking on one li ... Tat particular li only should be displayed

Answer (score 1):

This will alert the value of the LI you click on and then hide all the other LI elements:

```
​$('li').click(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
    $('li').hide();
    $(this).show();
});​​​​
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N8MUq/)** example.